# How give heading to second cell of table in html and how to have a table beside another table?

Tags: html, css, dojo, html-table

I have written something like this and want to give heading to second cell of table. Can anyone please tell how do I do that?

```
<tr>
   <td><label for="prodnumber">Search string for product number</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="prodnumber" name="prodnumber" size="40" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"/></td>
   <td><input type="checkBox" id="prodnumber" name="prodnumber" dojoType="dijit.form.CheckBox"/></td>
</tr>
```

Also please someone tell me how to have a table beside another table?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. Where do you want this heading? In a separate cell (and if so which)? Or as a <h3> or something inside the cell? As for a table beside another table, a table is a block-display element in CSS, so any of the methods of layout in CSS will work - perhaps most easily by using "float".

Answer (score 0):

For a detailed reference of how to build tables check out http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp. If you want to place two tables next to each other, you have to use the `float` CSS property. First you have to assign the table a fixed width and then set the float property for the two tables.

```
<div>
<table style="width:100px; float:left;">
  <tr><td>First Column</td></tr>
  <tr><td>First Column</td></tr>
</table>
<table style="width:100px; float:left;">
  <tr><td>First Column</td></tr>
  <tr><td>First Column</td></tr>
</table>
<p style="clear:both;"></p>
</div>
```